# Why is my Python list not passing through to another function that's dependent on the list even though it did in a less abstracted method?

Tags: python, list, abstraction

TRACE LOGS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../GradeCalculatorPlus/run.py", line 127, in <module>
calculate_grade_final(summatives, formatives, course)
File ".../GradeCalculatorPlus/run.py", line 60, in calculate_grade_final
lowest_grade_possible = lowest_grade(desired_end_grade, summatives, formatives)
File ".../GradeCalculatorPlus/run.py", line 38, in lowest_grade
if average(summatives_copy.append(next_summative_grade), formatives_copy) >= desiredGrade:
File ".../GradeCalculatorPlus/run.py", line 26, in average
int_summatives = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in summatives]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I know that one of the lists is not passing through properly to `lowest_grade()` but I can't figure out why.

I have heavily abstracted one method call in python. The top most call looks like this
(`summative` and `formative` are both empty lists that are initialized beforehand)

```
calculate_grade_final(summatives, formatives, course)
```

This call goes to the `calculate_grade_final()` method below

```
def calculate_grade_final(summatives, formatives, course):
    print('Please enter your FORMATIVE grades:')
    formatives = grade_loop(formatives)
    print('FORMATIVES for ' + str(course) + ':' + str(formatives))
    print('Please enter your SUMMATIVE grades:')
    summatives = grade_loop(summatives)
    print('SUMMATIVES for ' + str(course) + ':' + str(summatives))
    # https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Weighted-Average
    average_grade = average(summatives, formatives)
    print('Average for ' + str(course) + ':' + str(average_grade))
    desired_end_grade = input('What is your desired end grade for ' + str(course) + '? ')
    lowest_grade_possible = lowest_grade(desired_end_grade, summatives, formatives)
    print('The lowest possible grade you can get to get a ' + str(desired_end_grade) + ' for ' + str(
        course) + ' is either a SUMMATIVE grade of ' + str(
        lowest_grade_possible[0]) + ' OR a FORMATIVE grade of ' + str(lowest_grade_possible[1]))
```

The issue then goes to the `lowest_grade()` method which looks like this:

```
def lowest_grade(desiredGrade, summatives, formatives):
    possibilities = []
    summatives_copy = summatives
    formatives_copy = formatives
    for next_summative_grade in range(101):
        if average(summatives_copy.append(next_summative_grade), formatives_copy) >= desiredGrade:
            possibilities.append(next_summative_grade)
            break
    for next_formative_grade in range(101):
        if average(summatives_copy, formatives_copy.append(next_formative_grade)) >= desiredGrade:
            possibilities.append(next_formative_grade)
            break
    return possibilities
```

Which then goes to the `average()` method which looks like this:

```
def average(summatives, formatives):
    # summatives and formatives are stored in a list of strings so I quickly convert it into a list of integers
    # basically the array is like ['97','56','44'] and I convert it into [97,56,44]
    int_summatives = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in summatives]
    int_formatives = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in formatives]
    return (mean(int_summatives) * summative_weighting_factor) + (
                mean(int_formatives) * formative_weighting_factor)
```

However the `average()` method is throwing a NoneType error based on the Python traceback despite the fact that I called it earlier in `calculate_grade_final()` which resulted in the course grade average of 92

TERMINAL INPUTS:

```
Please enter your FORMATIVE grades:
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)98
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)100
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)100
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)100
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)98
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)97
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)100
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)100
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)stop
FORMATIVES for AP American Lit Lang/Comp:['98', '100', '100', '100', '98', '97', '100', '100']
Please enter your SUMMATIVE grades:
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)93
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)85
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)92
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)95
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)88
Enter a number grade (no fractions or percentages!) (Type 'stop' to stop the loop)stop
SUMMATIVES for AP American Lit Lang/Comp:['93', '85', '92', '95', '88']
Average for AP American Lit Lang/Comp:92.73124999999999
What is your desired end grade for AP American Lit Lang/Comp? 95
```

(the last input (`95`) is what breaks the program and causes the average() method to somehow not get the `summative` and `formative` lists despite average() working for the `Average for AP American Lit Lang/Comp:92.73124999999999` line of input)

I tried adding a copy of the `summative` and `formative` lists to `lowest_grade()` because I thought it would fix the problem of the lists not passing through to the final `average()` method but that didn't work either.

Comment: The problem is that `summatives` is None.  You haven't shown us how that variable is created.

Comment: Also, `summatives_copy = summatives` this code does NOT make a copy.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry I forgot to add in the question: the data for `summatives` and `formatives` is added through a different function but since the function works as intended I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `lowest_grade` function, make seperate step for append and then pass the list to `average` and do check there

change here, dont do `append` in the `average` function. do that in the previous step and pass the updated list to function to do checking

-> `if average(summatives_copy.append(next_summative_grade), formatives_copy) >= desiredGrade:`

->`if average(summatives_copy, formatives_copy.append(next_formative_grade)) >= desiredGrade:`